# Строка в C++ Ошибка с типами данных

Tags: c++

Из строки `3257,3,2,7,8,,, 7,7 97`  найти первое число, в данном случае это 3257. Вывод нужен именно целочисленный.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=0,s=0;
    string h="3257,3,2,7,8,,, 7,7 97",g="",l="";
    for (int i=0;i<h.size();i++){
        g=h[i];
        if (g==" " || g==",") {
            break;
        }
        else{
            l.push_back(h[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<l.size()-1;i++){
        g=l[l.size()-1-i];
        s+=g*pow(10,i);
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка на 18 строке.

```
|18|error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and '__gnu_cxx::__promote_2<int, int, double, double>::__type {aka double}')|
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки. Не заставляйте людей считать строки вашей программы

Comment: ну а какого черта вы пытаетесь строку умножить на число? Какой результат вы хотите получить от такой операции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s += g * pow(10, i);
```

`g` - Это строка, а вы ее на что-то умножить хотите - это как?

```
for (int i=0;i<l.size()-1;i++){
    g=l[l.size()-1-i];
    s+=g*pow(10,i);
}
```

этим кодом вы хотите строку перевести в число, но это жуткий изврат или такое задание?

`std::stoi` вас не устраивает для этой цели?

если же нужен именно изврат, то ваш код должен выглядеть тогда так:

```
for (int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
    const char letter=l[l.size()-1-i];
    const int digit = letter - '0';
    s+=digit*pow(10,i);
}
```

т.е. у вас и в этой строке ошибка

```
for (int i=0;i<l.size()-1;i++){
```

и надо

```
for (int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
```

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться, по невнимательности забыл. stoi вполне сойдет, но почему вы берете именно константы для char и int?

Comment: @Forer, `но почему вы берете именно константы для char и int?` потому что в ASCII символы `"0",",2","3","4","5",...` идут друг за другом и очень просто превратить их в числа просто вычев из кода символа код символа "0" - грубо говоря дешевый и быстрый способ перевода буквы в цифру (для char)

Comment: @Forer потому что всё, что не изменяется, надо делать константным